# Previous cell not disappearing in UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I have a table which initially has no data, and shows a `UITableViewCell` with a message saying the user has no data to show.

I have a method that gets called on `viewDidLoad` and reloads the table data. When this happens, the first table cell is still shown, and the remaining cells are below it with proper data. The first cell still shows the empty data message. Is there anything i'm missing here? I have my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath tableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifierEmpty = @"TableViewCellEmpty";

    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] numberOfObjects] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierEmpty];
        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierEmpty];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

            cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            cell.tag = -1;
        }
        return [self setTextForEmptyCell:cell];
    }

    MyObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = // Set values
    }
    // Set cell details        
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a cell when you don't have any data, why not add a simple `UILabel` to your tableView and toggle it's `hidden` state according to availability of data? Any view added to table view will scroll with it, and will give the **look** that the label is inside a cell. This does not answer your question, but it does solve your issue. Also, you avoid creating a second type of cell.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. But it's not the right solution... The right solution is to figure out why the cell won't disappear. Not sure why...very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was a threading issue while grabbing data from the server using `AFNetworking`. Check all the blocks where a new thread is being used!